# .htaccess help, replacing URI segment

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL that looks like this...

```
http://www.domain/a/var
```

I am hoping it would be possible to rewrite the URL using [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) so that `/a/` would be replaced by `/b/`.

Is that possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^a/(.*)    /b/$1

Answer (score 1):

This should do that you need

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/a/(.*) /b/$1
```

Note: You'll need to add [PT] or similar if you need mod_alias or mod_index or similar to work using the new path.